# Can a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be countable? If so, how to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis

Ok, so I'm having a little trouble with a bigger proof. A smaller piece of it is if a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $N(x,r,\mathbb{R}^n)$, is countable and, if so, how to prove it.

I'm trying to show that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable knowing that the intersection of the subset and a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable.

Any help would at all would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^n$ has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$, the cardinality of the real line. This follows immediately from the fact that if $\varnothing\ne U\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is open, then there are open intervals $(a_k,b_k)\subseteq\Bbb R$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ such that $$\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k,b_k)\subseteq U\;.$$ To see this, fix $c_k\in(a_k,b_k)$ for $k=1,\dots,n-1$, and observe that

$$\{c_1\}\times\{c_2\}\times\ldots\times\{c_{n-1}\}\times(a_n,b_n)\subseteq \prod_{k=1}^n(a_k,b_k)\subseteq U\;,$$

and there is an obvious bijection between $\{c_1\}\times\{c_2\}\times\ldots\times\{c_{n-1}\}\times(a_n,b_n)$ and $(a_n,b_n)$, which is well-known to have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.

In short, every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^n$ contains an open line segment.

Comment: @Potato - I apologize. I typed union when I meant intersection. So, if $N(x,r,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is uncountable, how can $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be countable?

Comment: @DesperateFluffy: I don’t understand the question: what is the relationship between $N(x,r)$ and $A$?

Comment: I know $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and that for $x\in A$, $A\cap N(x,r,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is countable. I'm proving $A$ is countable.

Comment: @DesperateFluffy: To be sure that I understand: you have a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ such that each $x\in A$ has an open nbhd whose intersection with $A$ is countable?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: @DesperateFluffy: Take any countable base $\mathscr{B}$ for $\Bbb R^n$. For each $x\in A$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $B_x\cap A$ is countable. Then $A\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}(B_x\cap A)$, and $\bigcup_{x\in A}(B_x\cap A)$ is a union of countably many countable sets, so it’s countable.

Comment: ...I feel so stupid now. Thank you for your help! ^_^

Comment: @DesperateFluffy: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I assume $n\ge 1$. Any neighborhood of $x$ will contain an open ball centered at $x$. It is not hard to show this open ball is uncountable. Assume without loss of generality that the point is $0$. We can then consider the uncountable subset $(w,0,\dots)$ with $0<w<r$, where $r$ is the radius of the ball. This is clearly uncountable, so the ball is too.