# Does a bijection $f$ exists between $V$ and a an open set $W$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V$ be an open set in $\Bbb{R}^{r+1}$.

My **question** is: Does a bijection $f$ exist between $V$ and an open set $W$ in $\Bbb{R}^{r+1}$ such that $$f(y_1,y_2,...,y_{r+1})=(0,0,...,\alpha)\in W$$ such that $\alpha\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: On second read-through, I'm not sure I understand anymore what you're asking.

If you're asking whether for some arbitrary open set $V\subseteq \Bbb R^{r+1}$ containing a point $(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})$ there is an open set $W$ containing a point $(0,\dots,0,\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\ne0$ and a bijection $f:V\to W$ such that $$f(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})=(0,\dots,0,\alpha),$$ then the answer is yes. All non-empty open subsets of $\Bbb R^{r+1}$ [will have the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/323246/28900), so all we have to do is pick an open set $W$ containing some point $(0,...,0,\alpha)$, let $g:V\to W$ be a bijection, and if $g(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})\ne(0,\dots,0,\alpha)$, then since there is a point $(x_1,\dots,x_{r+1})\in V$ such that $g(x_1,\dots,x_{r+1})=(0,\dots,0,\alpha)$, we can define a function $f:V\to W$ by $$f(z_1,\dots,z_{r+1})=\begin{cases}(0,\dots,0,\alpha) & \text{if }(z_1,\dots,z_{r+1})=(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})\\g(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1}) & \text{if }(z_1,\dots,z_{r+1})=(x_1,\dots,x_{r+1})\\g(z_1,\dots,z_{r+1}) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ $f$ will then be the desired bijection. Otherwise, $g$ itself is our desired bijection.

If you're asking whether for some arbitrary open set $V$ there is an open set $W$ and a bijection $f:V\to W$ such that for all $(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})\in V$ there is some $\alpha\neq 0$ such that $$f(y_1,\dots,y_{r+1})=(0,\dots,0,\alpha),$$ then the answer is no. In order for that to happen, we would need $$W\subseteq\{(0,\dots,0,\alpha)\in\Bbb R^{r+1}:\alpha\neq 0\},$$ but then $W$ isn't open in $\Bbb R^{r+1}$ unless it's empty, so non-empty open set $V$ of $\Bbb R^{r+1}$ provides a counterexample.